# Elliptic motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, orbital-motion, rotational-kinematics

I'm given the following motion:
$$x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)\\y(t)=B\sin(\omega t)$$
I'm asked to describe what kind of motion it is and other things. The thing that puzzles me is that my first approach was to express $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{A^2\cos^2(\theta)+B^2\sin^2(\theta)}.$$ But this led me to a wrong graph, and wrong stuff. I have figured out another way to solve this, but can someone explain me where the first approach got wrong?
I leave the graph of the wrong (purple) and right (red) graphs.

[image]

Comment: Why not graph the equations as a set of parametric equations instead? That would certainly get you the right shape too. To graph parametrically on Desmos you'd just write your function as $(x(\theta), y(\theta))$ and then you'd get your ellipse.

Comment: That is true, and I already did so(I just didn't put it in the image). I noticed that the parametric gives an ellipse, just as the correct formula in the image does. But what I'm asking is why the pythagorean formula fails to draw it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if when you are writing the parametric equation of an ellipse $x(t) = a \cos(t),\space y(t) = b \sin(t)$, the angle $t$ is **not the polar angle of a point on the ellipse** (point P shown on the ellipse), but that of point **A** on the circle of radius $a$. So if you want to write the polar equation of an ellipse, you shouldn't think of using this angle as the angle in $r(\theta)$.

(PS. Please ignore the inner circle of radius $b$, and the point **B**).
[image]

Comment: That is illuminating, you're amazing. I got what you're saying. But before giving you the correct answer mark I'd like to pose one more question given this answer:
If I want to calculate r given $\theta$ I guess we can say I have to use the non-pythagorean formula, buuut if I want to know r in function of the time I have to use the pythagorean formula and NOT the other one, right?

Comment: If you are referring $\theta$ to be the polar angle of the point on the ellipse, then $r$ is given by formula $1$ on the desmos webpage. However if $t$ or $\theta$ is used as in $x = A\cos(\theta), \space y = B\sin(\theta)$-equation, the second equation is perfect! This $\theta$ is the angle $t$ shown in my figure, made with point on the circle. However you shouldn't use this $\theta$ to plot the ellipse as $r(\theta)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, really clear